# How to remove title space of jfreechart chartpanel?

Tags: jfreechart, title

Hi i am new to jfreechart.

I want to remove the space allocated for title of the linechart's chartpanel in jfreechart.

Because I need to set height and width of chartpanel with the border of 10 pixels of the top panel which holds the chartpanel.

Pls help me..

Thanks in advance..

[image]

In the above graph I mentioned that at the top of the graph (title space) should be removed.so that i dont want to leave any space there.

If I did not give any title , it takes that space to display that graph.

Comment: Can you show some code / an SSCCE of your problem? I'm not sure what you mean by the 'space allocated for title' - when I construct a JFreeChart without a title, there is no space reserved for the title.

Comment: I want to remove the title as well as the space allocated for the title.

Comment: Again, show some *code* as an SSCCE...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign empty string to title parameter in Create************Chart() function.

Fox example:

```
final JFreeChart result = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
        "",  //Empty title
        "Time", 
        "Value",
        dataset, 
        true, 
        true, 
        false
    );
```

Comment: or you can set the title to null